# Need to run Javascript on web form before body onload event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm developing an asp.net web application.In that application i need to execute some java-script before form's `body-onload` event.

### Html markup

```
<body onload="ShowWait();">
   ......
</body>
```

Here I'm running `ShowWait();` on `body-onload`.
This script shows a please wait window.
But i need to run this code before this event.
Is there any event that help me to run script before page load.

Answer (score 3):

Given the function is called `ShowWait()`, you don't *"need to run JavaScript before page load"*, but you want to *"display a loading screen until the page has loaded"*.

Just put the loading element in your HTML and remove it using JavaScript after the page has loaded.

Comment: +1 this is generally the way to go with these things. Same technique is applied for lazy loading of images.

Answer (score 0):

Put a script tag in the head element with the script you want to run

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put that line in a script tag as first line in your body? It will run as the first thing.

Answer (score -1):

If you put Javascript statements (rather than function definitions) inside a  tag, they will be executed during page loading - before the onLoad event is fired.

```
<html>
 <body>
   <h2>First header</h2>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     alert("Hi, I am here"); 
     document.write("<h3>This is Javascript generated</h3>");
   </script>
   <h2>Second header</h2>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The caveat is that you cannot search for elements by ID because these element might not have been rendered yet, so your ability to change the page that way is limited.

Bottom line: possible, not recommended.

What I usually do in such situations is as follows:

```
Make the parts of the page that may change invisible (via style="visibility:hidden;");
Make onLoad run a Javascript code that changes the page and then sets the visibility of the said parts to visibility:visible.
```

Comment: i have changed my answer see